# does http redirection happens before request body is sent or after?

Tags: node.js, ssl, redirect, nginx, https

Say user makes a request (get|post) to `http://example.com/data`

now i've server setup, nginx, to redirect all requests to https.

so browser again sends a request but via https protocol.

my question is did server tell browser to redirect right after reading http headers or it could have gotten data in body of request and then told browser please send this via https.

because if latter, sensitive data has already been sent via insecure method.

I understand to prevent this i can include redirection in html file, are there any other methods.

Comment: *"I understand to prevent this i can include redirection in html file, ..."* - I doubt this will help. If you want to make sure that no sensitive data are transmitted with HTTP you have to make sure that no attempt is made to sent the data with HTTP in the first place. What might help are HSTS headers so that (at least the supported browsers) will never try HTTP after the first visit or that your server only supports HTTPS and not HTTP at all, i.e. that TCP connections to the HTTP port will fail already.

Comment: I mean if user insists on sending via http then nothing i can do, i could via HSTS force to send it via HTTPS and help with Auto redirection at through server software (nginx) etc.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter if the server reads it, because the client might have sent it anyway.

At the time when the server has finished reading the headers, the client has already sent the headers (obviously) but it also has sent *some or all of the body*.

How much of the body has been sent by the client is not dependent on HTTP, but on the underlying TCP protocol. It is dictated by variables such as the receive window, the congestion window and the size of the headers and of the body.

[See this great article](https://hpbn.co/building-blocks-of-tcp/#congestion-avoidance-and-control) for an explanation about congestion/receive windows in TCP.

Comment: before http request happens, handshake occurs if using https where some information about https config is exchanged.. Now if not using https server could still maybe tell hey i want to do ssl handshake so rerequest via https.

Comment: @MuhaMmadUmer there's no HTTP handshake, just TCP handshake. The redirect happens at the HTTP layer, so the client had already sent data